# Submit jobs to Celery from Perl

Tags: perl, celery

We're looking at replacing our homegrown async job manager with Celery.  Our webapp is Perl, and we currently submit jobs as json strings to rabbitmq, and we'd continue using rabbitmq as the message broker.  What's the best way to submit jobs to Celery?  I don't see a Celery module on CPAN.

Comment: Eh, it seems you'll have to write your own bindings. You can look at the [RCelery](https://github.com/leapfrogdevelopment/rcelery) project to see how such bindings can be written.